# Define group of taglib definitions xmlns

Tags: jsf-2, namespaces, facelets, taglib

Most of my .xhtml facelets starts with something like this

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions"
xmlns:comps="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/comps">
```

Is it possible to define this as a group in a common place and have all the files point to it?

so that when I decide to start using a new library, it can be easily accessed in any file.

Comment: As far as I see, that's simply not possible. Even if it was, how about IDE autocomplete and so on?